# How do I train my NER model using Trainer from huggingface?

Tags: python, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, huggingface

I'm having trouble using Trainer from HuggingFace to train my NER model.

My data looks like this :

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'tokens', 'ner_tags', '__index_level_0__'],
        num_rows: 985
    })
    val: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'tokens', 'ner_tags', '__index_level_0__'],
        num_rows: 123
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['id', 'tokens', 'ner_tags', '__index_level_0__'],
        num_rows: 124
    })
})
```

First I'm using this code to align the NER tags

```
def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):

    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples["tokens"], padding='max_length', max_length=512, truncation=True, is_split_into_words=True)

    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples[f"ner_tags"]):

        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)  # Map tokens to their respective word.
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
      
        for word_idx in word_ids:  # Set the special tokens to -100.
      
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:  # Only label the first token of a given word.
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            else:
                label_ids.append(-100)
      
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
      
        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    
    return tokenized_inputs
```

next, I tokenize my data and create my DataCollator:

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForTokenClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BertTokenizerFast

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
tokenized_wnut = my_dataset_dict.map(tokenize_and_align_labels, batched=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")
```

and finally, I create my metrics function,

```
def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

    true_predictions = [
        [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_labels = [
        [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]

    results = seqeval.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        "precision": results["overall_precision"],
        "recall": results["overall_recall"],
        "f1": results["overall_f1"],
        "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
    }
```

and then define my model and try to train it

```
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", num_labels=len(label_list))

from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from transformers import BertForTokenClassification

# Training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="my_awesome_ner_model",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    push_to_hub=True,
)

# Create the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_wnut["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_wnut["val"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

# Start training
trainer.train()
```

But I get this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-fff6be1cc4d7> in <cell line: 30>()
     28 
     29 # Start training
---> 30 trainer.train()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1542                 # Disable progress bars when uploading models during checkpoints to avoid polluting stdout
   1543                 hf_hub_utils.disable_progress_bars()
-> 1544                 return inner_training_loop(
   1545                     args=args,
   1546                     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1833 
   1834                 with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
-> 1835                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1836 
   1837                 if (

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2677 
   2678         with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2679             loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2680 
   2681         if self.args.n_gpu > 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2702         else:
   2703             labels = None
-> 2704         outputs = model(**inputs)
   2705         # Save past state if it exists
   2706         # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1754         return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
   1755 
-> 1756         outputs = self.bert(
   1757             input_ids,
   1758             attention_mask=attention_mask,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    968         elif input_ids is not None:
    969             self.warn_if_padding_and_no_attention_mask(input_ids, attention_mask)
--> 970             input_shape = input_ids.size()
    971         elif inputs_embeds is not None:
    972             input_shape = inputs_embeds.size()[:-1]

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```